# MongoDB find where key equals string from array

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to find in a collection all of the documents that have the given key equal to one of the strings in an array.

Heres an example of the collection.

```
{
  roomId = 'room1',
  name = 'first'
},
{
  roomId = 'room2',
  name = 'second'
},
{
  roomId = 'room3',
  name = 'third'
}
```

And heres an example of the array to look through.

```
[ 'room2', 'room3' ]
```

What i thought would work is...

```
collection.find({ roomId : { $in : [ 'room2', 'room3' ]}}, function( e, r )
{
  // r should return the second and third room
});
```

How can i achieve this?

One way this could be solve would be to do a for loop...

```
var roomIds = [ 'room2', 'room3' ];
for ( var i=0; i < roomIds.length; i++ )
{
  collection.find({ id : roomIds[ i ]})
}
```

But this is not ideal....

Comment: Are these standalone documents or are they embedded into some "hotel" document? What do you actually get as a result?

Comment: The 3 documents you see are root documents in a collection.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you posted should work - no looping required. The [`$in`](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-$in) operator does the job:

```
> db.Room.insert({ "_id" : 1, name: 'first'});
> db.Room.insert({ "_id" : 2, name: 'second'});
> db.Room.insert({ "_id" : 3, name: 'third'});
> // test w/ int
> db.Room.find({ "_id" : { $in : [1, 2] }});
{ "_id" : 1, "name" : "first" }
{ "_id" : 2, "name" : "second" }
> // test w/ strings
> db.Room.find({ "name" : { $in : ['first', 'third'] }});
{ "_id" : 1, "name" : "first" }
{ "_id" : 3, "name" : "third" }
```

Isn't that what you expect?

Tested w/ MongoDB 2.1.1

Comment: Ahh your correct, it is working... It appears the query is working but the update i had in mind is not. I want that each room in the array is found, (which currently is working) and that they are all updated with `{ $addToSet : { members : member.id }}`. But the update is not working. It appears only the first item found is being updated. How can i change this?

Comment: Ahh found it, i use `{ multi : true }`. Thanks for getting me in the right direction.